# Does wireless card need to be on same channel as AP to sniff beacon frames?

Tags: wireless, python, packet, aircrack-ng, 802.1x

**OBJECTIVE**

Essentially, my goal is to emulate something like `airodump-ng wlan0`

[Here is a link just in case ... **airodump-ng**](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airodump-ng)

- Collects raw 802.11 frames
- Displays nearby access points and data

---

**GAMEPLAN / OBSERVATIONS**

I did a quick `airodump` to see if my results would be close to the same. I see that `airodump` is *hopping channels* !!!!, collecting beacons, and displaying the nearby aps.

I want to see what I can pick up using [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) and `sniff()` without hopping channels.

**So**, I close `airodump` and fix my wireless card to channel 1 with `iwconfig wlan0 channel 1`.

**Then**, I use Scapy to `sniff()` beacon frames `subtype=8` from APs within range of my wireless card.

**However**, I compare my results to what I got from `airodump` and I see that I've got a bunch of beacons from APs on all different channels. I was expecting to only see beacons from channel 1.

---

**QUESTION**

Is this a glitch? Is there some sort of benefit that `airodump` gets from hopping channels or is it unnecessary to be on a specific channel to collect beacon frames from all channels?

Or does `sniff` have channel hopping built in?

Answer (score 1):

You can only listen to signals on the correct frequency band (channel).  This is why tools that attempt to give a full listing will **necessarily** browse through all the channels.

Comment: This is what I thought. Then how am I picking up beacons from different channels? I also tested with wireshark on channel 2. With that, I picked up beacons from aps that I knew were on channel 1 but the headers of the frame said channel 2 ...

Comment: `airodump` obviously scans the different channels regardless of what channel you previously set on the adapter.  As for the beacons you're picking up which indicate being on channel 2 are really on channel 2 and you were simply mislead for some reason.

Comment: I am saying that I used airodump to see what the true channel of the AP was. Then I used wireshark to scan for beacon frames on channel 2. I picked up beacons from the ap that I knew was on channel 1, but the header for the frame stated channel 2. Also, using sniff with scapy I picked up the same beacon from the ap on channel 1 while my wireless card was on channel 2.

Comment: Is it possible that you're seeing two different APs or an AP which supports two channels (possibly through channel bonding)?

Comment: By "supports two channels" you mean 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz? Would that enable an access point to be on channel 1 and 6 or channel 6 and 11 at the same time?

Comment: That's not what I meant and the reason I mentioned the possibility of channel bonding.

Comment: Based on what I've read about channel bonding. This is entirely possible. Could the results that I am experiencing also be due to 'channel overlapping'? Since there are only 3 distinct channels 1, 6, 11 could it be that my being on channel 2 could pick up beacons from channel 1?

Comment: No.  Channel overlapping only causes interference on the neighboring channels, not a recognizable message.

Answer (score 1):

What really happens is that to modulate and demodulate the signal your WIFI card antenna needs to operate on a frequency called central-frequency, which belongs to a certain channel which is being transmitted by the AP.
Your card antenna can only demodulate the 802.11 frames that hit your card on a **carrier frequency**(of the channel) which should match the frequency at which your wifi NIC is operating.

So in order to sniff all beacon frames, you need to be on all the frequency channels simultaneously to catch them, which is (obviously)not possible with single hardware antenna so you have to opt for frequency hopping like all other tools like airodump-ng.

They do this by creating a virtual interface for wifi and putting it into monitor mode, where it can sniff packets.